# Probability of being away from mean for independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be independent random variables drawn uniformly from $[-1,1]$. The [(weak) law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) says that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\text{Pr}\left(\left|\frac{X_1+\ldots+X_n}{n}\right|>0.1\right)=0.$$ But for what functions $f(n)$ can we say that $$\text{Pr}\left(\left|\frac{X_1+\ldots+X_n}{n}\right|>0.1\right)<f(n)?$$ For example, is it true for $f(n)=c/2^n$ for some constant $c$?

I thought this would be answered by the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem), but it doesn't seem to follow directly (or at least I don't understand it well enough.)

Comment: One that doesn't allow for negative values for one...

Comment: This link might be helpful? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin–Hall_distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Hoeffding's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_inequality#Hoeffding.27s_inequality) 
$$\text{Pr}\left(\left|\bar X\right|>\epsilon\right)\le 2\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\epsilon^2n\right)$$

Comment: Isn't it $n^2$ instead of $n$?

Comment: @nan: nope. you have $\text{const}\times \frac{n^2}{n}$

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get this from the usual proof of WLLN for random variables with finite variance.

We have $\Bbb E X_j^2=1/2$. Hence $$\Bbb E\frac{|X_1+\dots+X_n|^2}{n^2}=\frac1{2n}.$$So Chebyschev's inequality says the probabilty you ask about is no larger than...